# Can I have my cats in the cabin with me on British Airways European flights?

Tags: pets, british-airways

If I'm flying with BA intra-Europe (Stockholm-London), am I allowed to have my cats (in their cat-cage obv) in the cabin, under a seat or on my lap or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears not, [according to the British Airways website](http://www.baworldcargo.com/products/liveanimals.shtml?site=/products/liveanimals.shtml):

> Making your booking and taking your flight
>
> The DEFRA Export Section (Dogs and Cats) will advise you of the
>   current documentation and vaccination requirements for your
>   destination. We will also require a health certificate from your vet
>   to show that your pet is fit for air travel.
>
> When you make your booking you will need to let your travel agent or
>   British Airways booking representative know that you will be
>   travelling with a pet.
>
> Your pet will not be able to check in with you but will be handled
>   professionally by British Airways World Cargo, a cargo booking will be
>   required which can be requested through the local British Airways
>   World Cargo booking office.
>
> On the day of travel, deliver your pet to the British Airways World
>   Cargo Office. The travel container will be checked and the appropriate
>   charges collected. Please check local payment options when making your
>   booking.

Answer (score 3):

BA have a [really good page about pets](http://www.britishairways.com/travel/pet/public/en_gb) on their site

The bad news is that only guide dogs are allowed to be taken on the plane with you. All others must travel in the hold.